# php how to avoid negative answer

Tags: php, numbers, tax, negative-zero

Hi I am a newbe and writing a simple code for tax purposes. So far I have wrote a small code but I think there seems to be a problem with the function `taxable_i($i)` which is not letting me make `$taxable_i` `NIL`. I have tried everything. 
When I try to made `$taxable_i` `NIL` via function it wont let me do it. It shows me a result of `£13900`. I think the program is echoing `$taxable_i` rather then the tax payable. 
If I delete the above all together then the tax payable comes to `-£2199.80`, which is in minus. 
Please note that I put `$taxable_i <personal_allowance` so that the answer is zero but the result is not zero. I do not know why and what I am doing wrong. 
Any help is most welcome.'

```
<?php
// VAT 
define("vat_threshold",83000 );
define("vat_rate",0.2 );

// RELIEFS
define("personal_allowance",11000 );

//RATES
define("starting_rate",0 );
define("basic_rate",0.2 );
define("higher_rate",0.4 );
define("add_rate",0.45 );
define("divs_ord_rate",0.075 );
define("divs_uuper_rate",0.325 );
define("divs_add_rate",0.381 );

// THRESHOLDS
define("savings_income_band",5000 );
define("basic_rate_band",32000 );
define("higher_rate_band",150000 );
define("divs_allowance",5000 );

define ("band_0",0);
define("band_1",11000);
define("band_2",32000);
define("band_3",100000);
define("band_4",122000);
define("band_5",150000);

function taxable_i($i) {

    if ($i <= band_1 ) {
        $taxable_i = $i * 0;
        return $taxable_i;
    }
    if ($i <= band_3 ) {
        $taxable_i = $i - personal_allowance;
        return $taxable_i;
    } 
    if ($i >band_3 && $i <=band_4) {
        $taxable_i = $i - (personal_allowance-($i - band_3)/2);
        return $taxable_i;
    }
    if ($i > band_4) {
        $taxable_i = $i;
        return $taxable_i;
    }

}

$starting_income = $i = 1;
echo $i;    

$taxable_i = taxable_i($i);
echo $taxable_i;

switch ($taxable_i) {

case ($taxable_i > band_5):
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_5;
    $tax5 = $diff * add_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_5;
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_2;
    $tax4 = $diff * higher_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_2;
    $tax3 = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax5 + $tax4 + $tax3;
    break;

case ($taxable_i > band_2 && $taxable_i <= band_5 ):
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_2;
    $tax4 = $diff * higher_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_2;
    $tax3 = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax4 + $tax3;
    break;

case ($taxable_i < band_2):
    $tax = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax;
    break;

default:    
    $taxable_i <= band_0;
    $tax_payable == 0;
    break;
}

echo $tax_payable;
?>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant for code debugging or error finding chores. Please reduce the example to the minimal required code example necessary to showcase your problem, elaborate on what you are trying to achieve (and why) and point out the expected as opposed to the actual behavior.

Comment: I've been guilty of that too but... no, writing a tax programs will not help you do them. The only way to get taxes done, is to sit your sorry ass on a chair an do them :)

Comment: Hi Felix - unfortunately thats what I do for living. I am a tax advisor. Coding is my hobby. I have a tax calculator on my website www.sipheraccounting.com which was originally written in Excel using if statements. I always wanted to learn programming have now I have put around 30 days to write what I wrote. Hopefully I will get it working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put conditions in `case` statements, you should be using `if/elseif/else` there. The way `switch/case` works is that it compares the value of the initial `switch ()` expression with the values of each `case` expression. So it's comparing `$taxable_i` to the value of `$taxable_i > band_5`, so it's comparing a number to `true` or `false`.

Replace the `switch` block with:

```
if ($taxable_i > band_5) {
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_5;
    $tax5 = $diff * add_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_5;
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_2;
    $tax4 = $diff * higher_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_2;
    $tax3 = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax5 + $tax4 + $tax3;
}

elseif ($taxable_i > band_2 ) {
    $diff = $taxable_i - band_2;
    $tax4 = $diff * higher_rate;
    $taxable_i = band_2;
    $tax3 = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax4 + $tax3;
}

elseif ($taxable_i >= band_0) {
    $tax = $taxable_i * basic_rate;
    $tax_payable = $tax;
}

else {    
    $tax_payable == 0;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar. It works now.